# PHP code to calculate if three sides equal a triangle

Tags: php

How would i go about writing the php code that would take the inputs of three form fields and calculate whether or not they result in a triangle?

Would the best way to go about be an if/else statement?

Comment: Great question. Where are your attempts located?

Comment: have you even tried to research something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is right, you would have to use if/ else, or at last I can not think of something else at the moment.

Here is a sample PHP code:

```
<?php
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
$c = $_GET['c'];

if (($a + $b > $c) && ($a + $c > $b) && ($b + $c > $a)) {
    echo "Yes, this is a triangle!";
} else {
    echo "No, this is not a triangle!";
}
```

To test use something like: `http://localhost/TriangleChecker.php?a=4&b=6&c=8`

Answer (score 0):

3 side lengths a, b, and c are a triangle if a+b>c, a+c>b, and b+c>a. Here's the function you need:

```
/**
* Determine If Three Side Lengths Are a Triangle
 * @param  integer  $a first length
 * @param  integer  $b second length
 * @param  integer  $c third lenght
 * @return boolean    true|false
 */
function isTriangle($a, $b, $c)
{
    return (($a + $b > $c) && ($a + $c > $b) && ($c + $b > $a));
}
```

---

Example:

```
$a = 10;
$b = 12;
$c = 34;

$ret = isTriangle($a, $b, $c);
//var_dump(isTriangle($a, $b, $c));
if ($ret)
   echo 'That\'s definitely a triangle';
else
   echo 'That is not a triangle';
```